# Convert rows to columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe

```
  Row0    x
  Row1    y
```

I would like to convert the rows to columns.

Expected output:

```
       x   y
 Row0
```

Comment: What happened to `Row1`? Perhaps [DataFrame.transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pandas-dataframe-transpose)?

Comment: what type of structure is it?Series or Dataframe?

Comment: @AnuragDabas dataframe

Comment: so `Row0    x` are  the columns?

Comment: @AnuragDabas I got that as a result of doing: df1['Axis'].drop_duplicates(keep='first'). where the axis column was then dropped

Comment: @AnuragDabas correction, it has been converted to a series

Comment: where Row1 goes?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you could do this:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'col':['x','y','z']})

pd.DataFrame(columns = [i for i in test['col']])
```

Or even this:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame(index=['x','y','z'])
test.T
```

Output:

```
    x   y   z
    __________
```